# Firestore Security Rules: has Only not working?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

```
match /User/{uniqueCode} {
        allow read: if true;
      allow write: if isAuth() &&
                            request.resource.data.uId == request.auth.uid;
      allow update: if request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys().hasOnly(['name']);
      allow delete: if false;
    }
```

Although using these rules, all value update freely
whats the wrong of my rules?

Comment: It's really hard to say what's going on based on a single line of security rules.Please edit your question to expand the rules to show a bit more context, and to include the minimal code that you run against these rules and that is giving you problems.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i do the change

Comment: Thanks for that . Please also show the minimal code that any of us can run to reproduce the problem you're asking about. That's important, as security rules on their own don't do anything. Only once you have code (and possibly existing data) can we see the whole picture.